# Why aren't my axes aligned with the viewbox in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I am using a viewbox to map data coordinates to the SVG display.

All the data seems to align with the viewbox (I'm using a red border to show the viewbox boundary and a blue border to show the SVG boundary) but the axis lines are offset by exactly 0.5 in both dimensions.

Interestingly the ticks are correctly anchored to where the axis should be (although slightly offset), it's only the axis lines that are offset.

I've tried older versions of d3 (I went back several versions to 5.3.0 from 3 years ago but all had the same behaviour)

I can see that the `path` specification for the axis is incorrect in the resulting HTML output, but not why - e.g. for the y axis,

```
<path class="domain" stroke="currentColor" d="M-0.2,0.5H0.5V12.5H-0.2"></path>
```

should really be

```
<path class="domain" stroke="currentColor" d="M-0.2,0.0H0.0V12.5H-0.2"></path>
```

and the ticks are `translate`d incorrectly too by an extra y offset of 0.5 (this one should either not be transformed or use `translate(0,0)`):

```
<g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0,0.5)"><line stroke="currentColor" x2="-0.2"></line><text fill="currentColor" x="-0.35000000000000003" dy="0.32em">0</text></g>
```

Reproduction test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    fill: none;
}

rect {
    fill: #bbb;
    stroke: #222;
    stroke-width: 0.05;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 0.1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.debug {
    fill: none;
}

.debug.red {
    stroke: #f44;
}

.debug.blue {
    stroke: #44f;
}
</style>

</head><body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.1/d3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var data = [[0,0], [3,3], [10,10]]
var width = 12
var height = 12

const margin = 1.5

const graph = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("viewBox", d => `-${margin} -${margin} ${width+2*margin} ${height+2*margin}`)
        .attr("width", 600)

graph.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "debug blue")
    .attr("x", -margin)
    .attr("y", -margin)
    .attr("width", width + 2 * margin)
    .attr("height", height + 2 * margin)

graph.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "debug red")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

const scaleY = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, height]).range([0, height])
const axisY = d3.axisLeft(scaleY).tickSize(0.2).tickPadding(0.1*margin)
const scaleX = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, width]).range([0, width])
const axisX = d3.axisBottom(scaleX).tickSize(0.2).tickPadding(0.1*margin)

graph.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(axisY)

graph.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(0,${height})`)
    .call(axisX)

const plot = graph.selectAll("plot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", d => { console.log(d); return d[0]})
        .attr("y", d => d[1])
        .attr("width", 0.8)
        .attr("height", 0.8)
</script>
</body></html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0uwk8ycp/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Around d3v4 or 5, D3 began incorporating an offset for axis ticks:

> Safari often botches shape-rendering: crispEdges, drawing a
> two-pixel-wide line even though the stroke-width is one pixel. Also,
> in the common case where the coordinates are rounded, using a
> half-pixel offset should produce crisp edges even without
> shape-rendering.
>
> I think we should use zero-based indexing for coordinates, such that y = 0 means the topmost pixel and x = 0 means the leftmost pixel, and therefore offsetting by +0.5 (not -0.5) in both x and y. ([source](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/issues/8))

This [has caught](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/issues/75) people off guard.

I'm not sure on the initial implementation, but as of d3v7 you can modify the offset with axis.offset():

> If offset is specified, sets the offset to the specified value in
> pixels and returns the axis. If offset is not specified, returns the
> current offset which defaults to 0 on devices with a devicePixelRatio
> greater than 1, and 0.5px otherwise. This default offset ensures crisp
> edges on low-resolution devices.

So the solution is most likely to move to d3v7 and use `axis.offset(0)`.

Comment: Thanks! Now working as expected in https://jsfiddle.net/0uwk8ycp/5/

I guess working in a small dimension viewbox (where 0.5px is huge!) makes this behaviour a lot more obvious.